# OpenGL texture color mapping

Tags: c, opengl

I would like to efficiently perform a mapping from integers to colors on a buffer sent to the GPU as a texture object.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
// setup the rendering pipeline and init the texture object
glBindTexture(glTEXTURE_2D, texture);

// data is an array of integers ranging from 0 to 3 of length 144 * 160 like this: [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, ..., 1]
glTexImage2D(glTexture_2D, 0, /* not sure what to put here */, 160, 144, glRGB, /* also not sure what to put here */, data);
```

I want to be able to map the numbers from 0 to 3 into a RGB value.

I feel like I should be able to do this in a fragment shader, but how should I pass my data into the shader?

My fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

uniform sampler2D screen;

void main()
{
    /*
     * I would really like to be able to get the byte value
     * at the texture's coordinate that we are processing and 
     * use an if ... else if ... else ... block to map the texture
     */
     // FragColor = texture(screen, TexCoord);
}
```

Comment: How do you want to map those values?  Do you mean `0=black`, `1=red`, `2=blue`, and `3=green`?  I don't understand the mapping process you are proposing.

Comment: exactly, where black/red/blue/green is some arbitrary rgb value

Comment: you can use 1D texture with the colors for remaping ...

Comment: so something like this? `glTexImage(glTexture_1D, 0, glRGB, 160 * 144, 0, glRGB, glUNSIGNED_BYTE, data)`?